# Proving $\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a-1)(c+1)}{1+bc+c}\geq 0$ for positive $a$, $b$, $c$ with $abc=1$.

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

I recently saw the following inequality,
$$\frac{(a-1)(c+1)}{1+bc+c}+\frac{(b-1)(a+1)}{1+ca+a} + \frac{(c-1)(b+1)}{1+ab+b} \geq 0 \tag1$$
for all $abc=1$ and $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}_+ \setminus \{0 \}$.

To prove this inequality, I thought to try to look at each term, by knowing that $abc=1$, and as such we could express the three terms of our inequalities in terms of three/two variables and eliminate the denominator.

First, we shall look at the expression:
$$\frac{(a-1)(c+1)}{1+bc+c} = \frac{(a-1)(\frac{1}{ab}+1)}{1+ b \frac{1}{ab}+\frac{1}{ab}} = \frac{\frac{(a-1)(ab+1)}{ab}}{1+  \frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{ab}} = \frac{(a-1)(ab+1)}{ab(1+  \frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{ab})} = \frac{(a-1)(ab+1)}{ab+  {b}+{1}}$$
One can see that the denominator now is the same as the denominator of the third term of our inequality. Thus, we shall also bring the denominator of the second term to the form $ab+b+1$. We have

$$\frac{(b-1)(a+1)}{1+ca+a}=\frac{(b-1)(a+1)}{1+\frac{1}{ab}a+a} = \frac{(b-1)(a+1)}{1+\frac{1}{b}+a} = \frac{(b-1)(a+1)b}{b(1+\frac{1}{b}+a)} = \frac{(b-1)(ab+b)}{b+1+ab} = \frac{(b-1)(ab+b)}{ab+b+1}$$

Now we will sum our terms now with the same denominator,
\begin{align*}
I &= \frac{(a-1)(ab+1)}{ab+  {b}+{1}} + \frac{(b-1)(ab+b)}{ab+b+1} +\frac{(c-1)(b+1)}{1+ab+b} \\ &= \frac{(a-1)(ab+1)+(b-1)(ab+b)+(c-1)(b+1)}{ab+  {b}+{1}} 
\end{align*}
with
$$I=\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a-1)(c+1)}{1+bc+c} $$
Thus
$$I = \frac{a^2b+a-ab-1+ab^2+b^2-ab-b+bc+c-b-1}{ab+  {b}+{1}}$$
So
$$I = \frac{a^2b+ab^2 -2(ab+b+1)+b^2+bc+a+c}{ab+  {b}+{1}}$$
Now we must prove that
$$\frac{a^2b+ab^2 -2(ab+b+1)+b^2+bc+a+c}{ab+  {b}+{1}} \geq 0$$
Since $a,b,c$ are positive real numbers, $ab+b+1 \in \mathbb{R}_+^*$, so we now are left to prove
$$a^2b+ab^2 -2(ab+b+1)+b^2+bc+a+c \geq 0$$
$$a^2b+ab^2+b^2+bc+a+c \geq 2(ab+b+1)$$
Note. Here, AM-GM would be a good idea to use. I am currently thinking about a way to use it.
If anybody has a solution or a hint, it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: Construe the problem as $\left(\frac{R}{S} + \frac{T}{U} + \frac{V}{W}\right) \geq 0.$ My first try, **which might not bear fruit** would be to re-express the left hand side as $\frac{(R\times U\times W) + (T\times S\times W) + (V\times S\times U)}{S \times U \times W}.$  Then try to simplify, then try to use that $a\times b \times c$ = 1.  Note that the denominator of this re-expression **has to be positive**, since $a,b,c$ are all positive.

Comment: There are two key **meta-cheating** points of advice: (1) Consider the problem's **context**.  That is, if you haven't been studying the AM-GM theorem in class, why would you be given a problem that requires its use?  Taking your query tags at face value, you have a algebra-precalculus tag.  This suggests that the tools that you have been studying in your class should be sufficient to solve the problem. ...see next comment

Comment: (2) Your first try should be to *explore by some sort of baby-step*, rather than swinging for the fences.  Take slow, simple, investigatory steps of **any sort that you can think of**, and see where they lead.

Comment: You made two basic mistakes in presenting your question: (a) you did not provide **context** - that is, you did not describe those theorems or previous (solved) problems that have been presented in your class that lead up to this problem. (b) Re your "impasse": you did not provide *full details* in your query of all the actual work (e.g. algebra) that you have tried so far.

Comment: I am sorry about the use of the tag. This inequality is not from any class, but rather from an olympiad site. I will provide more detailed steps of what I've tried so far. The context, if you'd like, is the theory document: https://artofproblemsolving.com/articles/files/MildorfInequalities.pdf . The problem itself is from a Romanian site that prepares students for the NMO. I will cite this site if you'd like.

Comment: I think your algebra-precalculus tag is **accurate**, even though the problem may ultimately require use of Calculus (at this point, who knows).  Very helpful response, re **context**.  This means that you have to be prepared for a solution that (ultimately) may not be elementary.  Thus, the AM-GM theorem may be involved.  However, the "baby steps" idea + "showing all of your work" idea both still stand.

Comment: I am now editing my post for a more comprehensive try at a solution. I may reach a simpler inequality to solve. I will soon update with some other ideas.

Comment: Check these solutions https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cfrac%7B(a-1)(c%2B1)%7D%7B1%2Bbc%2Bc%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B(b-1)(a%2B1)%7D%7B1%2Bca%2Ba%7D%20%2B%20%5Cfrac%7B(c-1)(b%2B1)%7D%7B1%2Bab%2Bb%7D%20%5Cgeq%200%24&p=1.

Comment: @DariusChitu Very nice detail, very elegant reasoning.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: A common trick in an inequality like this is to substitute:
$$a = \frac xy, b = \frac yz, c = \frac zx$$
which transforms your final inequality to:
$$(x^3z+y^3x+z^3y) + (x^2y^2+z^2x^2+y^2z^2)\geq 2xyz(x+y+z).$$

But the above is easy: you can suitably use AM-GM and prove that two expressions in parentheses is at least $xyz(x+y+z).$ I will leave the AM-GM part for you to find the coefficients.

Comment: Thank you very much! This hint is extremely helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Now, use AM-GM:
$$ab^2+a\geq2ab,$$
$$b^2+1\geq2b$$ and $$a^2b+bc+c\geq3\sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2}=3.$$
After summing we'll get your last inequality.

Comment: Thank you for helping. This is a nice us of AM-GM.